# Obtener imagen de facebook con firebase

Tags: firebase, imagen, facebook

quiero saber como puedo obtener la imagen de facebook usando firebase ya que si obtengo el correo pero no la imagen, y también el usuario, pero la imagen no la toma correctamente, a que se debe?

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
            // UID specific to the provider
            String uid = profile.getUid();
            // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
            name = profile.getDisplayName();
            email = profile.getEmail();
            photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();
        }
    }

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.LayoutDraw);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.Nav_draw);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    /* USER PROFILE DATA INITIALIZE*/
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    email_user = headerView.findViewById(R.id.email_user);
    email_user.setText(email);
    name_user = headerView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_header_user);
    name_user.setText(name);
    image_header = headerView.findViewById(R.id.mainprofile);
    Picasso
            .with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(photoUrl)
            .error(R.drawable.persona)
            .into(image_header);
```

Comment: cual es tu codigo?

Comment: Déjame agregarlo a la pregunta